# How does this particular pointer increment work in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

sample code:

```
int arr[] = {1,9,3,4};
int *myarr;

//Scenario 1
myarr = &arr[0];

cout<<"array at [0] "<< *myarr <<endl;

*myarr++;

cout<<"array at [1] "<< *myarr <<endl;

//Scenario 2

myarr = &arr[0];

cout<<"array at [0] "<< *myarr <<endl;

myarr++;

cout<<"array at [1] "<< *myarr <<endl;

//Scenario 3

myarr = &arr[0];

cout<<"array at [0] "<< *myarr <<endl;

(*myarr)++;

cout<<"array at [1] "<< *myarr <<endl;
```

I can understand Scenario 3 statement. But not how myarr++ and *myarr++ work the same way.

Used codeblocks to execute the above statements.

Output is as follows:

```
array at [0] 1
array at [1] 9
array at [0] 1
array at [1] 9
array at [0] 1
array at [1] 2
```

Edit: I have edited to remove comments and added clarifications. Apologies for confusion caused

Comment: the second-to-last line doesn't print 2. Then the next line is undefined behaviour due to out-of-bounds access.

Comment: @M.M Actually no. That line passes a pointer to the operator << .

Comment: @DannyuNDos amended comment

Comment: @M.M I can only understand the comments if the statements are executed exclusively (ie either one of them)

Comment: @tobi303 if that were the case, the first output would be `1`, not `2`

Comment: @john could you confirm (and clarify in the question) if those statements are meant to be executed exclusively (ie only one of them, but not all of them in the order you show them here). Otherwise the comments dont make sense

Comment: @M.M right, now I am a bit confused. There are just too many comments in that code for my taste ;)

Comment: If you are beginner, then do yourself a favour and stay away from c-style arrays in C++ until you really need them (believe it or not this will take quite a while). Use container instead, eg `std::vector`

Comment: `*myarr;` dereferences the pointer to get the element pointed to (and does nothing with it). `myarr++;` increments the pointer. To confuse things, you can also do both things at once `*myarr++;`.

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks for the answer. So myarr++ and *myarr++  both mean the same thing which is a bit confusing when it comes to using the dereference operator "*". While there are already several ways to access elements of the array- myarr[0], *(myarr+0), *myarr+0, *(0+myarr), incrementing the pointer to point to next address location/element in the array, should not have involved the dereference operator.

Comment: @tobi303 I have edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: Your code is more related to C language than C++, because except logging (cout) you use only C features.

Comment: @Jean-ChristopheBlanchard I thought it is as much C++ as it is C. Aren't pointers integral to C++ also ?

Comment: They are part of c++, but for what you are doing in the example one would not use them in c++. Actually i avoid c style arrays and raw poonters whenever possible. As mentioned before you should take a look at std::vector, this will help you much more in learning C++.

Comment: @tobi303 thanks, I will surely look into the vectors.

Answer (score 0):

The first two times you increment the pointer `myarr`. That means you first print element 0, and then element 1. The third time you increment the value at the pointer `myarr`, not the pointer itself, and then you print that element again (but now incremented with 1).

This is because `myarr++` and `*myarr++` do the same thing - increment `myarr`. The second also dereferences it, but you ignore the value from that. `(*myarr)++` explicitly dereferences first, and then increments the dereferenced pointer - ie, the value it points to, not the pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you think it is an anamoly in the language that myarr++ and *myarr++ (with the use of dereferencing operator) both mean the same thing ?

Comment: Not really - it's the same statement, and precedence rules say that `++` binds closer than `*...` so `*myarr++` mean `*(myarr++)`.

Comment: Yes *myarr+ and *(myarr++) and myarr++ are same. But use of dereference operator is confusing in this context. Whenever we use the dereference operator, we intend to point to the value at a particular address. And if we have to simply increment the pointer to the next address then we should not ideally be using the dereference operator. If u have noticed (*myarr)++ is not same as *myarr++ or *(myarr++). See how confusing it is ? This is what I meant

Comment: I would recommend turning on basic warnings in your compiler - `-Wall` in GCC or Clang - which enables `-Wunused-value` that this code would trigger. There's nothing confusing or odd about the language until you at least use what the compiler already tells you.